# how to restrict the image in only one language in xhtml

Tags: jsf

I need to include an image in the xhtml page but when I add the image it is showing in all the languages. I want to restict the image only to one english language.

how to restrict it?

```
<h:graphicImage value="#{resource['images:register_img.png']}"  alt="image" width="560px" height="140px" />
```

Comment: can you show how this is currently showing ("in all the languages?")

Comment: the image is showing in all languages, the above is the graphic image value.